# Hide/Collapse Attributes in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, attributes, code-formatting

We have some code which uses attributes with long string Parameters (descriptions and the like) - it would be great, if we could hide attributes or at least its Parameters.

Is it possible to hide/collapse attributes (in C# code) in Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 3):

1. You can declare your parameter as a private constant:

   ```
   private const string LongTextParam = "Some very long text ...";

   ...

   [MyAttribute(LongTextParam)]
   public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
   ```
2. [#region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx) can help you:

   ```
   #region MyAttribute
   [MyAttribute("A very long string parameter .... ")]
   #endregion
   public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
   ```

Editor in Visual Studio can collapse such regions.

Also you can combine both approaches - move param text into private field / constant and wrap it with region.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible, but you can use regions

```
    #region SomeShortDescription
    [MyAttribute("Long description here...")]
    #endregion
```

For more information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed out, this can't be done currently on VS.

The suggested solution of using regions will probably work although I would advise against it.

I can see how attributes can be obstrusive if you have many, or just a few but they have many, or long, parameters, but they might be an essential part of your code and without seeing it you might miss something fundamental.

My 2 cents.